# soname confusion

Tags: gcc, clang, dynamic-linking

I read in many places about the 'real' library name and the symbolic link name.

But I want to understand how exactly the linker is searching?
Sometimes i see three different patterns of setting up the libraries. -> means the symbolic link

1. libxxx.so -> libxxx.so.1 -> libxxx.so.1.6.3
2. libxxx.so.1->libxxx.so.1.6.3
3. libxxx.so -> libxxx.so.1.6.3

and readelf -a xxx | grep SONAME shows libxxx.so.1. for all the real and symbolic links.
what i don;t understand is how the linker search.  now suppose i tell the linker i want to -lxxx, would the linker go find the filename with libxxx.so, or it will search for libxxx.so.1?  if the former, it means 2 won't work; if latter, it means 3 won't work. but i think all 1,2,3 works? or not? so does it mean linker searches what matches the prefix?